# Integer factorization in C language

Tags: c

I am making a program in C to make the output look like this:

```
2 = 2
3 = 3
4 = 2 x 2
5 = 5
6 = 2 x 3
....
102 = 2 x 3 x 17
103 = 103
104 = 2 x 2 x 2 x 13
```

I wrote the integer factorization code in the following way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXNUM 1000

int main(){
int num,numfordiv;
int div = 2;
for (num=2;num<MAXNUM;num++){
    printf("%d=", num);
    numfordiv = num;
    if(num%div != 0){
        div = div+1;
    }
    else{
        numfordiv = numfordiv / div;
        printf("%d x ",div);
        if(numfordiv == 1){
            div = 2;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

However, this does not work for unknown reason. Is there anything wrong with the loop?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Is there an error message or does the actual behaviour differ from the expected behaviour? Although not explicitly stated, from your  examples you seem to expect a factorization into prime numbers; is that the case?

Comment: Your goal is a bit unclear. How would you do for example 9? would it be 3x3 or 9? In any case I would implement this with at least one subfunction and some recursive loops.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do to generate the output requested is, at least,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXNUM 1000

int main()
{
    int num,numfordiv;
    int div = 2;
    for (num=2;num<MAXNUM;num++)
    {
        printf("%d= ", num);
        numfordiv = num;

        div = 2;

        while (numfordiv>1)
        {
            if(numfordiv%div != 0)
            {
                div++;
            }
            else
            {
                numfordiv /= div;
                printf("%d ",div);
                if(numfordiv != 1)
                {
                    printf("x ");
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see you need:

1. An inner loop to loops on all possible dividers
2. For each number you must reset your divider
3. The modulo operation must be performed on the divided number

Comment: thanks very much for your help. and I actually got it work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @LP is nice and simple to understand.

However, if performance matters it has a drawback for very high `MAXNUM` values. Since `div` is just incremented by one in the `while` loop, performance will be bad for high numbers as the code tests a lot of div-values that will fail. A simple example: There is no need for setting `div` to 4, 6, 8, 10, etc.

Below is an example that will perform better for high numbers. The price is more complex code and more memory usage.

The basic idea is to collect primes when detected and only set `div` to prime values so that the code skips a lot of numbers that will never pass the `%` test anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXNUM 200000000
#define INCREASE_BY 1000

int main()
{
    // Make array for collecting primes
    int primes_array_size = INCREASE_BY;
    int *primes = malloc(primes_array_size * sizeof(int));
    if (primes == NULL)
    {
        printf("out of memory\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // Add 2 as the first prime
    primes[0] = 2;
    int num_primes = 1;
    int prime_pos = 0;

    int num,numfordiv;
    int div = 2;

    for (num=2;num<MAXNUM;num++)
    {
        div = primes[0];
        prime_pos = 0;

        printf("%d = ", num);
        numfordiv = num;

        while(numfordiv>1)
        {
            if(numfordiv % div != 0)
            {
                // Goto next prime (if there are any)
                ++prime_pos;
                if (prime_pos < num_primes)
                {
                    div = primes[prime_pos];
                }
                else
                {
                    // No more primes in the list
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                numfordiv = numfordiv / div;
                printf("%d",div);
                if (numfordiv != 1) printf(" x ");
            }
        }

        if (numfordiv != 1)
        {
            // Found new prime - add it
            primes[num_primes] = num;
            ++num_primes;
            printf("%d",num);

            if (num_primes == primes_array_size)
            {
                // Allocate more memory
                primes_array_size = primes_array_size + INCREASE_BY;
                int* tmp = realloc(primes, primes_array_size * sizeof(int));
                if (tmp == NULL)
                {
                    printf("out of memory\n");
                    free(primes);
                    return 0;
                }
                primes = tmp;
            }

        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    free(primes);
    return 0;
}
```